# using distcp to copy from on-prem to azure blob

Tags: parquet, azure-blob-storage, distcp

I'm trying to copy petitioned parquet files (created by sqoop) to Azure Blob using distcpt utility but with no luck. I'm runing my code on Hadoop Hortonworks 2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91. I can create folders and files using:
`hadoop fs -D hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=localjceks://file/tmp/test.jceks` So there is no issue with accessing the blob.

When I try to copy data using the following command:

```
hadoop distcp -D hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=localjceks://file/tmp/azureb.jceks -skipcrccheck -update hdfs://xxxx.xxxx.com:8020/tmp/dataset wasb://monthdeparq@daghrq.blob.core.windows.net/dataset/
```

I get this error:

```
18/04/11 15:51:34 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
18/04/11 15:51:34 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
18/04/11 15:51:34 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: azure-file-system metrics system started
18/04/11 15:51:34 INFO tools.DistCp: Input Options: DistCpOptions{atomicCommit=false, syncFolder=true, deleteMissing=false, ignoreFailures=false, overwrite=false, append=false, useDiff=false, fromSnapshot=null, toSnapshot=null, skipCRC=true, blocking=true, numListstatusThreads=0, maxMaps=20, mapBandwidth=100, sslConfigurationFile='null', copyStrategy='uniformsize', preserveStatus=[], preserveRawXattrs=false, atomicWorkPath=null, logPath=null, sourceFileListing=null, sourcePaths=[hdfs//xxxx.xxxx.com:8020/tmp/dataset], targetPath=wasb://monthdeparq@daghrq.blob.core.windows.net/dataset/, targetPathExists=true, filtersFile='null', verboseLog=false}
18/04/11 15:51:35 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at xxxx.xxxx.com/10.177.202.112:8050
18/04/11 15:51:35 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at xxxx.xxxx.com/10.177.202.112:10200
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO tools.SimpleCopyListing: Paths (files+dirs) cnt = 11; dirCnt = 3
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO tools.SimpleCopyListing: Build file listing completed.
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO tools.DistCp: Number of paths in the copy list: 11
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO tools.DistCp: Number of paths in the copy list: 11
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at xxxx.xxxx.com/10.177.202.112:8050
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at xxxx.xxxx.com/10.177.202.112:10200
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:7
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1521872749815_0031
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1521872749815_0031
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http//xxxx.xxxx.com:8088/proxy/application_1521872749815_0031/
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO tools.DistCp: DistCp job-id: job_1521872749815_0031
18/04/11 15:51:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1521872749815_0031
18/04/11 15:51:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1521872749815_0031 running in uber mode : false
18/04/11 15:51:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/04/11 15:51:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1521872749815_0031_m_000004_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: File copy failed: hdfs//xxxx.xxxx.com:8020/tmp/dataset/c8489a06-5e7a-4485-8d74-164ae7f8b932.parquet --> wasb://monthdeparq@daghrq.blob.core.windows.net/dataset/c8489a06-5e7a-4485-8d74-164ae7f8b932.parquet
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't run retriable-command: Copying hdfs//xxxx.xxxx.com:8020/tmp/dataset/c8489a06-5e7a-4485-8d74-164ae7f8b932.parquet to wasb://monthdeparq@daghrq.blob.core.windows.net/dataset/c8489a06-5e7a-4485-8d74-164ae7f8b932.parquet
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:296)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Uploads to to public accounts using anonymous access is prohibited.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.storeEmptyLinkFile(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:1725)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.createInternal(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1784)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1625)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1007)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyToFile(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doCopy(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doExecute(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:87)
        ... 11 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.

18/04/11 15:51:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1521872749815_0031_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: File copy failed: hdfs//xxxx.xxxx.com:8020/tmp/dataset/f6bdbb67-c47b-4cce-a872-60c39f4ac575.parquet --> wasb://monthdeparq@daghrq.blob.core.windows.net/dataset/f6bdbb67-c47b-4cce-a872-60c39f4ac575.parquet
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't run retriable-command: Copying hdfs//xxxx.xxxx.com:8020/tmp/dataset/f6bdbb67-c47b-4cce-a872-60c39f4ac575.parquet to wasb://monthdeparq@daghrq.blob.core.windows.net/dataset/f6bdbb67-c47b-4cce-a872-60c39f4ac575.parquet
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:296)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Uploads to to public accounts using anonymous access is prohibited.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.storeEmptyLinkFile(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:1725)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.createInternal(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1784)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.create(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1625)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1007)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyToFile(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doCopy(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doExecute(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:87)
        ... 11 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
```

I have tried the distcp with different parameters but I get the same errors. I have also tried it without -skipcrccheck -update but same issue.

Comment: In your stacktrace, I can see that: `Uploads to to public accounts using anonymous access is prohibited.` How do you authenticate to the blob storage ? Do you have a sas token ? a shared access key ???

Comment: I'm using a shared access key and the container is public

Comment: OK, are you able to copy/upload file using the blob storage SDK ? Using a basic feature

Comment: No, I used command line such as: hadoop fs -D hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=localjceks://file/tmp/azureb.jceks -ls  hdfs://xxxx.xxxx.com:8020/tmp/dataset wasb://monthdeparq@daghrq.blob.core.windows.net/dataset/

Comment: It seems to me that distcp ignores the credential file (jceks). The   hadoop fs -put command with the same jceks file works fine.